# Printf not printing to terminal in Apple Clang

Tags: c, macos, printf

We have started C programming in my Uni, and I appear to have fallen at the first hurdle. My very simple program will not print to the terminal. The code:

```
 #include "stdio.h"
     int main(){
     printf("Memory size for type %s = %lu \n", "double", sizeof(double));
     return 0;
 }
```

I have used all my google-fu, and have only found that I apparently should use `vprint`, but it won't take three arguments, only two. Also, bizarrely, printing to a file works! See screenshot:

[Terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvWg2.png)

Comment: Enable compiler warnings ans pay heed to them! `sizeof` yields a `size_t`, not an `unsigned long`. Use the correct type specifier (I'll leave that as a minor task to you). As given, you invoke undefined behaviour - no further research necessary.

Comment: Thank you to those who have answered. However, using %zu makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

The format specifier for `size_t`(the return type of `sizeof`) is `%zu`.

```
 printf("Memory size for type %s = %zu \n", "double", sizeof(double));
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, apparently, when I simply run the program, Clang prints the output to `a.out` in the same directory as the code, and there's nothing I can do about it. Whatever, as long as the code works - means I can turn it in, and I'll be checking my work with `./a.out`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, it appears that there is a misconception here :

```
gcc 1.c
```

gcc is used to compile the program (creating the executable, here using the source file 1.c), not to run it. The program might have been compiled under the name 'a.out'.

When you compile your program using :

```
gcc 1.c -o 1.txt
```

You are actually compiling the program with gcc and, using the option -o, creating the executable under the name 1.txt (a program can be named whatever you want, or almost)

Then when you type

```
./1.txt
```

you are actually running the program (1.txt) and you have the expected output.